# Changing the value of a boolean variable using ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and am making a web app which is supposed to filter out certain games depending on which day the team plays.  I'm trying to change the value of a boolean variable with an ng-click, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Here my HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MatchupController as matchupCtrl">
    <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="DayController as DayCtrl">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="tnf()">Thursday Games</button>

</div>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="team in matchupCtrl.teams" ng-hide="team.tnf">
    <div class="col-sm-5 well">
        <h3>Home</h3>
        {{team.home.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 well" >
        <h3>Away</h3>
        {{team.away.name}}
    </div>

</div>
```

...and my JS

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('MatchupController',function(){
   this.teams = matchUps;

});


var matchUps = [
{
    home:{ 
        name:'Cincinnati Bengals',
        homeImage:{'background-image': 'url(http://prod.static.bengals.clubs.nfl.com/assets/img/gbl-hd-bg.jpg)'},
    },
    away:{ 
        name:'Miami Dolphins',
    awayImage:{'background-image': 'url(http://blog-imgs-70.fc2.com/o/f/f/offseason2012/Dolphins.jpg)'},
},
    location: 'Paul Brown Stadium, Cincinnati',
    time: '8:25pm',
    date: "2016-09-29",
    tnf: false,
},
{
    home:{
        name:'Jaxonville Jaguars',
        homeImage:{'background-image':     'url(http://nfasl.spruz.com/gfile/75r4!-!JEHJEG!-!zrzor45!-!LJPKNQQG-JJSJ-    HHMR-NNJR-EPLFJOMGLIMD/jacksonville_jaguars_banner.jpg)'},
    },
    away:{
        name:'Indianapolis Colts',
        awayImage: {'background-image': 'url(http://www.851facebook.com/images/sports-nfl-afc-south-indianapolis_colts-night-football-rugby-facebook-timeline-cover-banner-for-fb-profile.jpg)'},
    },
    location: 'Wembley Stadium, London',
    time: '9:30am',
    date: "2016-10-02",
    snf: false,
           },
{
    home: {
        name:'Minnesota Vikings',
        homeImage: {'background-image': 'url(http://611enterprises.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Minnesota_Vikings_banner.jpg)'},  
    },
    away: {
        name: 'New York Giants',
        awayImage: {'background-image': 'url(http://www.covermyfb.com/media/covers/thumb/3895-new-york-giants.jpg)'},
    },
    location: 'U.S. Bank Stadium, Minneapolis',
    time: '8:30pm',
    date: "2016-10-03",
    mnf: false,
           }
]
app.controller('DayController',function() {
    var tnf = function() {
       matchUps.tnf = !matchUps.tnf;
        return matchUps.tnf;

    }
});
```

I want to change the value of tnf so it will hide in the display when the user clicks the button (i.e. changes the value of tnf to true).

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach `tnf()` to the controller's scope. The way you have it now, it is simply declared as a local variable and when the controller function finishes, the tnf function goes out of scope and will be garbage collected. Instead, you should do this:

```
app.controller('DayController',function() {
    this.tnf = function() {
       matchUps.tnf = !matchUps.tnf;
        return matchUps.tnf;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Even with the change, however, my functions still aren't working.  Here is a link to the source code (dashboard.html and js/controller.js being the main files). https://github.com/mmikeyd123/DevelopmentExcercise

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on. There may be a bunch of smaller issues. For example, I don't see where you have defined your routes.